# "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" in Magento 1.9.3.0

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I've only been able to find info regarding "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" in relation to Magento 2.

My install is a Magento ver. 1.9.3.0 hosted locally on Ampps.

When I try to Install New Extensions, I receive the "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" message.

[image]

This has only been happening since the upgrade from 1.9.2.4, it was working fine before that. Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Alternatively if you need immediate solution, you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it`s to late but Do this to solve your problem :

1. if you use AMPPS Software check (AMPPS installation directory)\PHP for existing file `cacert.pem`. If dosen`t exist make file`cacert.pem` in PHP directory of installation path.
2. copy content of [this file](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) then Paste in "cacert.pem" in PHP directory.

Now we need make path to file `cacert.pem`:

3. open `PHP.ini` file (if you use AMPPS you can right click on AMPPS icon on taskbar then Configuration then php)
4. search tag [curl] , then
5. under tag [curl] change line `;curl.cainfo =` to
   `curl.cainfo ={$path}\\{$php_dir}\cacert.pem`
   (this is path of cacert.pem )
6. save file `php.ini`
7. you need to restart php

in ampps right click on icon of ampps on taskbar and select stop
wait two seconds and then select start

8. i hope your problem be solve

this worked for me

Comment: Should be accepted as a right answer, solved my problem.
If start returns error: "SL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"
Replace file cacert.pem by this content: https://gist.github.com/VersatilityWerks/5719158/download